# Chaining semantic actions

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, boost-spirit-x3

I'm having trouble chaining semantic actions.

I want to parse a percentage (`X%` with `X` a real number) and return its value as a float between 0 and 1. I also want to fail if the percentage is higher than 100%.

What I have currently is a two almost trivially simple rules and some simple semantic actions:

```
const auto ensure_normalized = [](auto& context)
{
  const auto& value = _attr(context);

  _pass(context) = value >= 0 && value <= 1;
  _val(context) = _attr(context);
};

template<typename T, typename ContextType>
void multiply_by(T multiplier, ContextType& context)
{
  using value_type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(_val(context))>;
  using attribute_type = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(_attr(context))>;

  _val(context) = value_type(_attr(context) * attribute_type(multiplier));
}
constexpr auto divide_by_100 = [](auto& context) { multiply_by(.01f, context); };
const auto percentage = rule<struct percentage, float>{"percentage"}
                        = (float_ >> '%')[divide_by_100];
const auto normalized_percentage = rule<struct normalized_percentage, float>{"normalized_percentage"}
                                   = percentage[ensure_normalized];
```

This works for everything I have thrown at it just the way I expect. Thing is, I don't feel I'm doing this `The Right Way` (i.e. I don't think I'm using Boost.Spirit.X3 as intended). Especially the explosion of `rule`s makes this seem ridiculous.

If I try to apply the `ensure_normalized` semantic action directly to the first rule, e.g.

```
const auto normalized_percentage = rule<struct normalized_percentage, float>{"normalized_percentage"}
                                   =  ((float_ >> '%')[divide_by_100])[ensure_normalized];
```

I get a garbage value out. It also seems the assignment in `ensure_normalized` is somewhat of a hack. I just don't see how else to tell X3 what to do.

Code is on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/417666211e7b433c).

Comment: If code works as intended, [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be the more appropriate site to post the quesion...

Comment: `(float_ >> '%')[divide_by_100][divide_by_100][divide_by_100]` doesn't work either. The lambda is called 3 times, but only the first time it's called it has any effect. It looks like you can assign to `_val(context)` only once. I think than an additional rule wrapper is the best solution right now.